# AWS times out, cant upload my application

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

Can anyone help me debug what is wrong with what I am doing?  I have tried all kinds of things, watched like 10 tutorials, all say to do the same things, I can't get past this step regardless.  I always go to do a `eb create` and it just times out regardless of whether i increase the timeout or not. I just need some help on how to find the error here to be honest, as the logs don't show me anything, they time out when I request them.

I've tried this with like 5 different instances etc. with the same results every time, so I think it must be something on my end.  I have no idea what though so any help on how to figure out what it is is super appreciated.

```
Test (master$*=) % eb create    

Enter Environment Name
(default is MyApp-dev): 
Enter DNS CNAME prefix
(default is MyApp-dev): 

Select a load balancer type
1) classic
2) application
(default is 1): 1
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
Creating application version archive "app-290a2-170716_181834".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
Environment details for: MyApp-dev
  Application name: MyApp-dev
  Region: us-east-1
  Deployed Version: app-290a2-170716_181834
  Environment ID: e-pcx83hph3r
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/4.2.0
  Tier: WebServer-Standard
  CNAME: MyApp-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2017-07-16 22:18:59.183000+00:00
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-421594409424 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
INFO: Created security group named: XXXXXXX
INFO: Created load balancer named: XXXXXXX
INFO: Created security group named: XXXXXXX
INFO: Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: XXXXXXX
INFO: Environment health has transitioned to Pending. Initialization in progress (running for 11 seconds). There are no instances.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group named: XXXXXXX
INFO: Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: XXXXXXX
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: XXXXXXX
INFO: Added instance [i-0792b35263944c4c1] to your environment.
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: XXXXXXX
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: XXXXXXX

ERROR: The operation timed out. The state of the environment is unknown. The timeout can be set using the --timeout option.
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, and because it's a block of solid text it's difficult to read. What are you trying to achieve? What problem are you having? What have you tried? What steps fails? Make it easy for people to help you or they won't bother.

Comment: I'm literally just trying to debug this. All I've done is do `eb create` and `eb deploy`.  The step that fails is both of those, as I said above.  The error is the bottom of that log, as I said above. I just need to know how to debug this. Logs also time out when i request them, as I said above. I dont know what to provide you other than this